# How to make file manager moveable?

Tags: html, google-chrome

I am using a html input tag with type="file" as in this snippet.

Unfortunately it is not possible to drag the opening file explorer around.

Tested on: Chrome v80 MacOS

Is it possible to make the file dialog **draggable**?

```html
<input type="file">
```

[image]

Comment: That's the browser UI. I don't think there is any programatic way to influence this. You might get more helps on https://superuser.com

Comment: Note that while you can't move it in Chrome, you can still [resize it](https://superuser.com/questions/829397/how-can-i-resize-the-too-big-open-file-dialog-in-osx), and note also that Firefox uses the floating version of the file picker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it isn't. That's just how your browser / OS implement file picker dialogs.